# How to get logged in user information using JWT Authentication?

Tags: php, wordpress, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

In my WordPress REST API project, I need to get logged-in user data through API. I used the [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin for generating tokens. I have generated tokens with the parameters of  username and password of the user. [image]

Now using these tokens I have created one function in my API file but it sends me `0` as API response in Postman with the below Headers.

```
'Content-type': 'application/json', 
'Authorization': 'Bearer token_value'
```

Function code:

```
function get_loggedin_user_info(){
  global $current_user; 

  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  print_r($current_user);
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'endpoints/v1', '/logininfo', array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'get_loggedin_user_info'
    ));
});
```

So how can I get the logged-in user's data with the WordPress hook `wp_get_current_user()`

Secondly, how can I make the `jwt-auth/v1/token` API that will get the username and password as dynamic?

P.S I have added the RewriteCond and RewriteRule in the htacceess file and also include the JWT Auth Secret key in my config file.

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'secret-key');
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Be aware that you also can modify the JWT response when a successful login:

```
function mod_jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch( $data, $user ) {
    $user_info = get_user_by( 'email',  $user->data->user_email );
    $profile = array (
        'id' => $user_info->id,
        'user_first_name' => $user_info->first_name,
        'user_last_name' => $user_info->last_name,
        'user_email' => $user->data->user_email,
        'user_nicename' => $user->data->user_nicename,
        'user_display_name' => $user->data->display_name,
        'phone' => get_field( 'phone', "user_$user_info->id" ) // you also can get ACF fields
    );
    $response = array(
        'token' => $data['token'],
        'profile' => $profile
    );
    return $response;
}
add_filter( 'jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch', 'mod_jwt_auth_token_before_dispatch', 10, 2 );
```

In that way you do not need to call another endpoint to get more data from the user.

When the user comes back to your site/app, remember to first validate the token and then a good idea is to call the `/users/me` endpoint.

Again, if you want to return more information on `users/me`, you can do it:

```
    function add_custom_fields() {
        register_rest_field(
            'user', 
            'profile',
            array(
                'get_callback'    => 'get_custom_fields',
                'update_callback' => null,
                'schema'          => null,
            )
        );
    }
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_fields' );

    function get_custom_fields( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
        $user_info = get_user_by( 'id',  $object['id'] );
        $profile = array (
            'id' => $user_info->id,
            'user_first_name' => $user_info->first_name,
            'user_last_name' => $user_info->last_name,
            'user_email' => $user_info->user_email,
            'user_nicename' => $user_info->user_nicename,
            'user_display_name' => $user_info->display_name,
        );
        return $profile;
    }
```

Comment: Zoix my intention is users/me to return more data but i got a few question, where should i put this pieces of code, functions.php ? second will putting code like this effect the original users/me ?

Comment: Yep, `functions.php` is the right place. To your second question, yes, it will be affected, but just because you are adding more details to the response. The token stays intact.

Comment: understood mate, clean and clear explanation :p, greatful for your explanation mate, it will help me alot, thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this route: `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me`

send the token to this route and get the details of your user

I'm here if you have any question :)